# Swiper slideTo last slide, whilst snapping to left hand side

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, responsive, swiper.js

In Swiper demos, slides snap to the left of the screen until you get to the final slides, which are prevented from snapping to left because (I presume) Swiper doesn't want to show whitespace down the righthand side:

[image]

**Slide 10 will never snap to the left side**

https://swiperjs.com/demos/120-slides-per-view-auto.html

In my opinion it feels like a bug to the user, especially when you trigger slide to slide 10 and it only pops into the right side.

The workarounds I've found are to either add a blank slide, or to add margin-right to the final slide, so then slide will snap to the left side:

```
.swiper-slide:last-child {
  margin-right: calc(100vw - 300px);
}
```

[image]

**Add margin-right to last slide**

https://codepen.io/kmturley/pen/ExxrGgw

**Add blank slide at end**

https://codepen.io/kmturley/pen/JjjzKrK

**Use loop functionality and then hide duplicates**

https://codepen.io/kmturley/pen/oNNVLxL

Is there a better or built-in way to do? this without having to use a workaround?

I want to change this spacing dynamically later and if you change it manually, then you have to call swiper.update() causing layout updates. Also my current workaround requires you to know the width of the slides, or use custom javascript to calculate the widths. So a built-in or responsive solution would be preferable!

Comment: you should add loop true.. so its slide continuously.. no more space in right side

Comment: Loop is not ideal as I want the blank space. I've tried adding loop and hiding the duplicate slides, but that allows you to keep looping, unless I replace the next/prev with custom functions

Answer (score 1):

try to add loopedSlides: 8, and remove  margin-right: calc(100vw - 300px);

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  slidesPerView: 'auto',
  autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
  loopedSlides: 8,
});
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work? doesn't loopedSlides need to be used with loop?

Comment: When loop is enabled, you can keep tapping the arrows and eventually get back to Slide 1, so it's not ideal. but so close!

Comment: Looks like you can disable the arrows, and then it works!
https://codepen.io/kmturley/pen/oNNVLxL

Comment: if you add loop means.. no need loopedslides 8.. just try to add loop its works fine @Kim T

Answer (score 0):

Your current workaround probably is quite optimal and I don't htink there is any built in way to acheave what you are trying to do. However you could consider to use `loop: true` option and this could give a better user experience.

https://codepen.io/rentodesign/pen/gOOqNwo

Comment: I did try loop, but in my case I don't want to see the duplicate slides. I guess I could hide them with css.